# Compile error once run using the program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

## Main Program

```
package esss;
// Add
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import esss.DBI;
import esss.Shared;
import esss.Control;



public class deduction extends esss.Control {
protected DBI dbi;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  esss.Shared bean = (esss.Shared)session.getAttribute("shared");

  //String[] checked = request.getParameter("deduction");// needs parameter
  String type = request.getParameter("deduction");// needs parameter
  String amount = request.getParameter("amount");

  addDeduction(bean, type, amount);
  gotoPage("/mainPage.jsp", request, response);
}

public void addDeduction(esss.Shared bean,String type, String amount) throws ServletException{
  try {
    dbi = new esss.DBI();
    if(dbi.connect()) {
      String payment ="";
      if(type.equals("Parking Lot A")) {
        payment="10";
      }
      else if(type.equals("Parking Lot B")) {
        payment="5";
      }
      else if(type.equals("Extra Life Insurance(Age<35, 50,000)")) {
        payment="5";
      }
      else if(type.equals("Extra Life Insurance(Age 35-55, 25,000)")) {
        payment="17";
      }
      else if(type.equals("Extra Life Insurance(Age>55, 10,000)")) {
        payment="35";
      }

      if(!(type.equals("none"))) {
        String empId= bean.getEmpId();
        String dedDate = bean.getCurrentDate();
        //String dedId = bean.getdedId();
        //String dedname = bean.getdedName();
        //String dedAmount = bean.getAmount();
        dbi.updateDeduction(empId,dedId, dedName, type,dedDate);
        bean.setMessage("Deduction Added");
      }
      else {
        bean.setMessage("Please make sure you perfrom deduction");
      }
      dbi.close();
    }
    }catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      bean.setMessage("Exception caught : " + e);
      bean.setError("The database could not be connected");
    }
  }
}
```

## Complier Error

```
compile:
[javac] Compiling 22 source files to /home/student/mcintron/cps4931/maricarmen/build/WEB-INF/classes
[javac] /home/student/mcintron/cps4931/maricarmen/src/deduction.java:71: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable dedId
[javac] location: class esss.deduction
[javac]                     dbi.updateDeduction(empId,dedId, dedName, type,dedDate);
[javac]                                               ^
[javac] /home/student/mcintron/cps4931/maricarmen/src/deduction.java:71: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable dedName
[javac] location: class esss.deduction
[javac]                     dbi.updateDeduction(empId,dedId, dedName, type,dedDate);
[javac]                                                      ^
[javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

This is the main code and when I compile using the complier it gives me error. I couldn`t understand that why does it show this error?

Comment: This question is shit: Since you cannot read the clear compiler output, you will not be able to understand the answers in plain english as well. Furthermore, it is too narrow and answering it will not enrich anybody. It is just garbage in the Internet. Finally, it is a duplicate of your the closed question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252083/couldnt-compile-and-no-clue-what-to-do

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare those two variables, right?

In the line:

```
 dbi.updateDeduction(empId,dedId, dedName, type,dedDate);
```

both `dedId` and `dedName`

So you need to uncomment them... look carefully, just above. I'm guessing there may be another issue though. In general, if it says it can't find XYZ it means it wasn't even declared

Comment: do I need to put them in string?

Comment: Look above the line `dbi.updateDeduction(empId,dedId, dedName, type,dedDate);`  - need to remove comments

Answer (score 0):

`dedId` is not declared and i could find  the below line in comments, if you could uncomment your code or below line it might compile.

```
  //String dedId = bean.getdedId();
  //String dedname = bean.getdedName();
```

replace this one

```
//String dedId = bean.getdedId();
//String dedname = bean.getdedName();
```

with this one

```
 String dedId = bean.getdedId();
 String dedname = bean.getdedName();
```

Comment: no its says this error: [javac] /home/student/mcintron/cps4931/maricarmen/src/deduction.java:68: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method getdedId()
    [javac] location: class esss.Shared
    [javac]                     String dedId = bean.getdedId();

Comment: @Zain did you write `getdedName();` and `getdedId();` methods in your `Shared object`